# How to calculate the winding number of a facet's points?

Tags: math, lua, 3d, 2d

I have a flat square in 3D space made of 4 points, each made of (x,y,z) values. I have rotated this square and converted it to 2D points, so it is now made of (x,y) values.

I know that if the square is facing away from me I should not render it (it is actually the backside of a cube) and that this can be calculated by finding the "winding number" of the points which make up the 2D square.

I have the code below in Lua which almost works, but is hiding facets when they are not quite facing "away" from me. What is wrong with it? Have I missed something?

Thanks...

```
local function isPolygonClockwise( pointList )
    local area = 0

    for i = 1, #pointList-1, 2 do
        local pointStart = { x=pointList[i].x - pointList[1].x, y=pointList[i].y - pointList[1].y }
        local pointEnd = { x=pointList[i + 1].x - pointList[1].x, y=pointList[i + 1].y - pointList[1].y }
        area = area + (pointStart.x * -pointEnd.y) - (pointEnd.x * -pointStart.y)
    end

    return (area < 0)
end
```

Being Lua, the pointList is 1-based, not 0-based.

Here is a list of points which cause the front face of the cube to be rendered when it is pointing almost to the right but very definitely still facing away:

```
160.0588684082
-124.87889099121
160.0588684082
124.87889099121
41.876174926758
70.065422058105
41.876174926758
-70.065422058105
```

That list started original as winding anti-clockwise as a simple list of values of -100 or 100 for the x and y values of each corner.

Comment: Can you give a point list that gives the wrong answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised that the increment value was wrong because it was counting every value in the point list which means the x and y values were being counted twice after index 1...

```
local function isPolygonClockwise( pointList )
    local area = 0

    for i = 1, #pointList-1, 2 do
        local pointStart = { x=pointList[i].x - pointList[1].x, y=pointList[i].y - pointList[1].y }
        local pointEnd = { x=pointList[i + 1].x - pointList[1].x, y=pointList[i + 1].y - pointList[1].y }
        area = area + (pointStart.x * -pointEnd.y) - (pointEnd.x * -pointStart.y)
    end

    return (area < 0)
end
```